# How can i extend 2 classes inside one

Tags: dart

I have a navigation bar that leads me to the class "Busca". A second class "_BuscaSatet" already extends "Busca".

How can i make 2 classes to extend "Busca" as i created a third one "Categorias"

I am new to dart, tried doing this:

```
class Busca extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _BuscaState createState() => _BuscaState();

  _CategoriaState createState() => _CategoriaState();

}
```

and then

```
class _CategoriaState extends State<Busca> {
```

Comment: Multiple inheritances are not supported in modern languages because of ambiguity. Let say you have a method named m() in class A and m() (same name) in class B now you extend booth classes in class C now you try to access any one of the methods now the compiler will give an error so multiple inheritances are restricted. You can achieve the same thing by inheriting class A to Class B then class B to class C now class A & class B method will be available to class C. You can also use interface but it won't solve your problem, and mixins can be another solution.

Comment: I believe the issue here is more that overloading isn't supported in dart. It doesn't really make sense in this context either way.

Comment: `A second class "_BuscaSatet" already extends "Busca".` read your code carefully, BuscaState is NOT extends Busca class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking to provide "generic" return types for a single method, you might try the following, which allows you to specify the intended return type with generics on the function level rather than at the class level:

```
class MyClass {
  T createState<T>(...) {
    ...
    return T(...);
  }
}
```

Then you might call it as

```
MyClass myClass = MyClass();
OtherClass other = myClass.createState<OtherClass>(...);
```

Comment: Can you be more specific in which class should i do it? i am pretty new to this world.